# SQL Subquery to get actors in more than 30 films

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find all the names of actors that have participated in more than 30 films. This below isn't quite doing it. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM actor A
WHERE 30 > (SELECT COUNT(actor_id) FROM film_actor);
```

Tables involved:

- **actor:** actor_id first_name last_name last_update
- **film:** film_id title description release_year language_id original_language_id rental_duration rental_rate length replacement_cost rating special_features last_update
- **film_actor:** actor_id film_id last_update

Comment: Your subquery is going to count all the rows in film_actor regardless or what actor you're dealing with.  My suggestion would be to work backwards - start in film_actor - use GROUP BY, HAVING, and INNER JOIN to get back to get the actors you want.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT      a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM        actor       a
INNER JOIN  film_actor  fa  ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
GROUP BY    a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name
HAVING      COUNT(fa.film_id) > 30
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - couldn't see it when I was putting up my comment of working backwards up above

Answer (score 1):

**Behaviour explanation of your current query**

Your current query runs without any connection between `actor` and `film_actor` tables, so the results would be odd and would actually **show every actor** from the `actor` table if the number of rows in entire `film_actor` table with non-null value `actor_id` is less than 30.

---

**Right approach for the task**

Use `INNER JOIN` with grouping and having clause to only show actors who participated in at least 30 movies.

If a pair of `actor_id, film_id` in your table `film_actor` is unique then this query would suffice:

```
SELECT a.actor_id,a.first_name, a.last_name
FROM actor a
INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON
  a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name
HAVING COUNT(fa.film_id) > 30
```

However, if you are storing several roles an actor could play in a single movie, so that the pair mentioned earlier is not unique, then add distinct to the having clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fa.film_id) > 30
```

Note that I've added `actor_id` to select and group by clause since two actors can have the same first and last name and you'd probably want to see those cases clearly.

Answer (score 1):

> use joined query instead try this

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM actor a
JOIN actor_film af
ON(a.actor_id = af.actor_id)
WHERE (SELECT count(af.film_id) FROM af) > 30
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also good alternative, if we have common columns then it would better to use only one in GROUP BY and rest of with aggregate function as like below:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(a.first_name) AS first_name, 
    MAX(a.last_name) AS last_name 
FROM actor a
INNER JOIN film_actor  fa  ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id
HAVING COUNT(fa.film_id) > 30
```